# Get Level 1 entry on a section as Nav

Tags: navigation

I have a template which I want to use for different sections.

In my template I have this code:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('catering').level(1) %}
<ul>
  {% for page in pages %}
    <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I want to select the current section by Craft self. So I can use the same template for multiple sections.

Comment: If you're using entry types to control your templates have a look at https://craftcms.com/support/entry-type-templates

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. You can set the template for a section in the control panel. Maybe read through this article to get a grasp of it: http://withchief.com/blog/craft-cms-the-very-basics-of-templating

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment you could do this:

In `templates/_pages/index.twig` you would do:

`{% include '_pages/_types/_' ~ entry.type %}`

Then create a folder in `/templates/_pages/` called `_types` in it use, an example `_standard.twig` in which "standard" coincides to your Entry Type slug.

I hope that helps. I couldn't find the original SE post but I know that this method has been mentioned and preferred by many Crafters!

Answer (score 1):

What i want do is:

I will get all level 1 childs from the current Section to build a Subnav with it. Like:

`{% set pages = craft.entries.section(getCurrentSection).level(1) %}`

What i need to know is the current section handle. Thank you ;)

Comment: You really should update your question, not answering it in this way.